# JS filter on a JSON response

Tags: javascript, json, filter

unfortunately I'm not familiar with JS and I need to filter this string for example:

```
{
   "code":200,
   "success":true,
   "data":{
      "token":".J1e9ipFZkPE6EvIRAqEf9hp",
      "expires":"2019-01-05 14:18:43"
   },
   "time":0.009
}
```

Well it's obvious that I need to get the token value, I found out that there is jsonpath just like Xpath in XML but I have no idea about doing it in JS.

I would like to get your help on this

Comment: You've tagged this [tag:scriptlet]. Are you working with JavaScript or Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JSON.Parse()` and then get `data.token` value from Object:

```js
let response = '{"code":200,"success":true,"data":{"token":".J1e9ipFZkPE6EvIRAqEf9hp","expires":"2019-01-05 14:18:43"},"time":0.009}';

let parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response);

let token = parsedResponse.data.token;

console.log(token);
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean this?

```js
const text = '{ "code":200, "success":true, "data":{ "token":".J1e9ipFZkPE6EvIRAqEf9hp", "expires":"2019-01-05 14:18:43" }, "time":0.009 }'

const json = JSON.parse(text);
const token = json.data.token

console.log(token)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var mydata = JSON.parse('{ "code":200, "success":true, "data":{ "token":".J1e9ipFZkPE6EvIRAqEf9hp", "expires":"2019-01-05 14:18:43" }, "time":0.009 }');
alert(mydata.code);
alert(mydata.success);
alert(mydata.data.token);
```

Comment: Please explain your code

Comment: A common use of JSON is to exchange data to/from a web server. When receiving data from a web server, the data is always a string. Parse the data with JSON.parse(), and the data becomes a JavaScript object. So after that we can call using `mydata.item`